# Why does Grafana double the sub-page within the URL on certain links?

Tags: grafana, rancher

I'm using Grafana 7.1.5 under Kubernetes via the [Rancher Monitoring operator](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/monitoring-alerting/v2.5/), exposing it via the Nginx ingress controller with a sub-page of /grafana-metrics. `https://DNSNAME:PORT/grafana-metrics/` successfully retrieves a page with a "Welcome to Grafana" banner at the top and a number of dashboards on it.

Most of the links on the page work, such as the Grafana icon at the top of the left sidebar, the Search icon on the left sidebar, and the Home icon at the top left of the main panel (beside the Grafana icon, but not on the left sidebar). However, the Dashboard icon on the left sidebar, and all of the icons on the flyout menu that's shown from that icon, contain URLs that include the sub-page (`/grafana-metrics`) twice, such as `https://DNSNAME:PORT/grafana-metrics/grafana-metrics/dashboards`. The page source for those elements lists the URLs as simply `./grafana-metrics/dashboards` or similar, so the use of a relative URL that includes the sub-path appears to be what's causing the duplication, but I'm not sure whether that inclusion represents a misconfiguration on my part or a bug in the Grafana code.

I've configured the settings for serving Grafana from behind a sub path as described in https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/, including both a `root_url` matching the pattern on that page and `serve_from_sub_path = true`, and although I can see that Grafana fails completely to load if I remove those settings, I don't see it remove the subpath from the relative URL when they're enabled. I've also found no difference in behavior with the `domain` property set or omitted.

Can anyone shed any light on whether this is expected behavior that I just haven't yet found the setting to control, or if it's a bug for which I need to submit a bug report to the Grafana team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad I found this question because we've hit this issue and I thought I was going crazy, since there is little information about this to be found.

The issue lies, I believe, with Rancher. The monitoring operator deploys an internal nginx container that serves as a reverse proxy for Grafana, "grafana-proxy", part of the "rancher-monitoring-grafana" deployment. That nginx container rewrites the response body:

```
sub_filter '"url":"/' '"url":"./';
```

This rewrites the "navTree" JSON coming from Grafana, and rewrites "/grafana-metrics/dashboards" to "./grafana-metrics/dashboards", which in combination with the `<base href="/grafana-metrics" />` causes the duplicate context path in the links.

I don't have a solution for you yet, we are still taking to Rancher support, but I'm already posting this for other people who stumble upon this.

Comment: Like you, I'm glad to hear we're not the only ones hitting this, and the lack of a response before yours did have me wondering if this was somehow Rancher-specific. Thanks for working with Rancher's support on it. Can you please update your answer or comment when you have a bug ID or a planned fix version?